# MySQL: Changing databases in the middle of a script

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've never had to do this before, so really I just want to check and see if I'm approaching this the correct way.

I need to switch databases in the middle of a PHP script, and I'm not sure if there are any security issues, or memory issues, or etc...

So I have my connection code at the top of my page.

And in the middle I do the following:

```
mysql_select_db("new_db") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_db table ORDER BY name ASC");
// Rest of relevant code
```

Now is there a way to kill this connection afterwards, or do I need to switch back below this part?

Answer (score 1):

Just do a `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_db.table ORDER BY name ASC");`

without having to do a `mysql_select_db` if it's only for one query

Comment: because you don't have to call another mysql_select_db after